# Is the CD version of iWork '09 updatable to the newly released version?

Tags: software-update, iwork

Can I update the apps from iWork '09 installed from the DVD to the new versions in the App Store?

[image] [image]

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: I ask this because I don't want to install the suite (no way to select which apps to install) if I can't update them.

Comment: According to MacStories: "If you purchased iWork or Life in a box: You probably have either because you have an older Mac. You’ll have to purchase the new versions in the Mac App Store unless you buy a new Mac." Now, I don't know where they get their info, but that's the first comment I've seen on the matter.

Comment: @Dave I guess I'll have to find my DVD and my wive's superdrive, and test it for myself :S

Comment: @Dave Well, I made some enquiries and it seems MacStories was right at the time. The upgrade was not possible and some users complained. Apple's App Store team changed their mind on the matter after being made aware of Apple's official policy yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally reinstalled iWork from the iWork '09 disk.

At the following launch of the `App Store` I got a nice surprise.

[image: App Store : 3 Updates badge]

And each application can be updated separately. No need to launch them prior to the `App Store` update.

[image: 3 Updates available : Pages, Numbers, Keynote]

All in all, I am pleasantly surprised by apple's choice to support the version of iWork which was still updated outside of the App Store in Mountain Lion.

---

*Note*:

After installing Mavericks, I updated the up to date version of iWork on my wive's computer and both versions are now installed. While on mine the fresh install of iWorks '09 was simply replaced with the latest iWork from the App Store.

Comment: FYI, I woke up this morning, logged into my Mac, and noticed that each application was visible in the MAS Updates section as an individual update. Glad to see Apple fixed this.